# All table borders on Word document erased

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I am working with a 100 page document with around 15000 words and close to 30 tables. Upon opening the file I realized that all the table borders were erased. The table structures were preserved and I had to go through each of the tables and `repaint` all the borders.

How can I prevent this from happening again the future?

MS Word 2013 with no plugins or other problems. This was the first time this has happened.

Answer (score 0):

In  your word document it seems like the properties of table border has be resetted to none. Please follow the below steps to revert the border settings.

Click Table Tools > Design > Borders and make your selection. > All

or

Click Table Tools >  layout > properties > Borders and Shadings > Borders > All

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me with MS Word Office 365 ProPlus version on Windows PC today (2021-12-14). The document is 745 pages long. All borders in cca 700 tables were gone in an instance. I believe it's a bug.

The second option above solves the problem for 1 table and resets the border atrribute back to "All" (from "None").

If you have a reasonable number of tables you can set the first table manually clicking "Table Tools > layout > properties > Borders and Shadings > Borders > All" and then repeat the action for all the other tables by pressing F4 key while mouse-clicked within each of the tables.

If you have a very large number of tables, use this macro:

https://www.thedoctools.com/word-macros-tips/word-macros/apply-uniform-borders-to-all-tables/

Tu run the macro, use the Word menu Developer > Visual Basic > a window opens > right click your document within the navigational tree on the left > select View Code > paste the macro into the window > press Play icon.